# AngularJS and impressJS working with external JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, impress.js

Let's say I am using angular for data-bindings and prevent me from using repetitive code:

```
<div id="{{slide.id}}" class="step" data-x="{{slide.x}}" data-y="{{slide.y}}" data-z="{{slide.z}}" data-rotate-x="{{slide.rotateX}}" data-rotate-y="{{slide.rotateY}}" data-rotate-z="{{slide.rotateY}}" data-scale="{{slide.scale}}" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
  {{slide.content}}
</div>
```

As you can see, I prepared that `div` so that it iterates through each object in this this JSON file:

```
[
{
  "id":"overview",
  "x":3000,
  "y":1500,
  "z":0,
  "rotateX":0,
  "rotateY":0,
  "rotateZ":0,
  "scale":10,
  "content":"content2"
},
{
  "id":"slide_1",
  "x":1600,
  "y":1800,
  "z":-10,
  "rotateX":0,
  "rotateY":0,
  "rotateZ":0,
  "scale":1,
  "content":"content1"
},
]
```

The file perfectly loads using this:

```
App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('SlideCtrl', ($scope, $http) ->
$http.get('js/slides.json')
     .then((res)->
       $scope.slides = res.data
  )
)
```

But somehow the output looks like this:

[image: angular-impress output]

Is there anyone who actually implemented angular and impress together?

Comment: That works okay for me - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/409/ - are you sure it's not something in the CSS?

Comment: i think when using impress.js is the problem, impress cannot re-initialized when it has been initialized thus loading content from ajax doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also working on this.. but little differently.. and my code works 100%.
Here is my HTML Template

```
<div ng-controller="agendaController">
   <ul><li ng-repeat="agendaItem in agendaItems" id="agenda-{{agendaItem.id}}" class="step" data-x="{{agendaItem.x}}" data-y="{{agendaItem.y}}" data-scale="{{agendaItem.scale}}">
<q>{{agendaItem.content}}</q></li></ul>
</div>
```

and here is my javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('agendaController', function($scope){
$scope.agendaItems = [];
contents = [
    "Various Stages in Construction of a building",
    "Stake-holders & their levels of hierarchy from TCS to Labour",
    "Survey Reports"
];
for (i = 0, n = contents.length, x = -12000, y = -10000, scale = 2; i < n; i++) {
    data = {'id': (i + 1), 'x': x, 'y': y, 'scale': scale, 'content': contents[i]}
    $scope.agendaItems.push(data);
    y += 1000;
}
});
```